# How to saved a text always in buffer in Vim>

Tags: vim

Actually I want to copy a selected text from file a in Vim and paste to multiple different parts of file b. But when I paste to file b, it just happened once and then buffer is empty. I want that part of text in buffer always as I have to paste it to some more parts and for this I have to go to file a every time I had to copy and then paste to that file b. Is there any way that I can save that text in buffer always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up vim terminology here. From the [Vim Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ):

> A buffer is a file loaded into memory for editing.

What you mean by a `buffer` is actually a `register`. The default register gets overwritten by a lot of operations that delete text (e.g. `x/c/d`) because they store the deleted text in there. But you can yank 100K lines of text into a named registers like this:

```
"a100000yy
```

This yanks all these lines into register `a`.

Now go to file B and lets first delete the 100K lines you want to change. Put your cursor on the first line that needs to change and do:

```
100000dd
```

Then we will paste the lines from file A with:

```
"aP
```

Notice that that is a capital `P`.

For more information on the power of register check this link out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vim/vim_registers.htm

Comment: I basically yanked a block of 100K lines from file A and then paste to multiple areas in file B and I do that in Vim I guess which it is, but when I paste it once it perfectly happened. But when I paste it 2nd time it says Nothing in register. So how can I save a block of 100K selected text in register?

Comment: How do you paste exactly? Just using `p` or do you overwrite certain lines by selecting them in visual mode and than pasting? Are you using Vim or a do you use another variety like gvim?

Comment: I select part of text of 100K rowss by moving cursor to there and then [Ctrl + v,100000,Shift + g] and then I press y and its says block of 100K rows are yanked, in file a. Then, I open file b and select that part of text which I want to change by moving cursor to there and then [Ctrl + v,100000,Shift + g] and then I press p. But I want to do to other fields in file b but now it says nothing in register

Comment: `Ctrl + v` goes into visual block mode, which is probably not what you want. I altered my answer to break it down some more for your usecase.

Comment: Also, selecting text in visual mode and pasting over it will overwrite the default register with the selected text. Why your register is empty after pasting I don't know exactly. But your process does not work as you expect in general.